# Gstreamer: Turn YUV(4:2:2) raw video into mp4 (w/ h264 encoding)

Tags: gstreamer, mp4, h.264, yuv

This is what I'm running, however, it doesn't work. What's wrong with this command?

```sh
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=file.yuv ! video/x-raw, format=YUY2 ! decodebin ! \
               videoconvert ! omxh264enc ! queue ! filesink location=output.mp4
```

Error: Pipeline doesn't want to PAUSE
Error: Could not initialize supporting library

Answer (score 0):

Multiple things are wrong here. This one should get you closer at least..

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=file.yuv ! rawvideoparse format=yuy2, width=xxx, height=xxx ! \
videoconvert ! omxh264enc ! queue ! mp4mux ! filesink location=output.mp4
```